# Huge amount of virtual size used by sqlservr.exe - is that normal?

Tags: windows-7, sql-server

[image]

I'm checking memory leak on my computer currently, is that the high usage of virtual memory by the `sqlservr.exe` related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. SQL Server uses a lot of virtual address space. Microsoft recommends that you set your pagefile to 1.5x to 3x your RAM size, depending on your database - the larger if you have full text search enabled.